# Few questions on Kan Extensions

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Consider a small category $\mathcal{A}$ and its free completion with finite limits $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$.

- Is the inclusion $\mathcal{A} \to \hat{\mathcal{A}}$ fully faithful?
- Does the inclusion preserve finite limits?
- What about colimits?

Now let's say I have a functor $\mathcal{A} \to$ Set which is faithful.

- Can I extend it to a functor $\hat{\mathcal{A}} \to$ Set?
- What limits is this extension preserving?
- Is the extension faithful?
- Do you have a reference for this kind of questions?

Comment: The embedding of A^ into presehaves on A is fully faithful (in fact kind of an identity), and so is the yoneda embedding of A. Then the answer to your first question is yes

Answer (score 0):

$\require{AMScd}$

> Consider a small category $\mathcal{A}$ and its free completion with
>   finite limits $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$.
>
> - Is the inclusion $\mathcal{A} \to \hat{\mathcal{A}}$ fully faithful?

Yes; you have this diagram
$$
\begin{CD} 
{\cal A} @>j>> \hat{\cal A}\\
@| @VVyV\\
{\cal A} @>>y> PSh(\cal A)
\end{CD}
$$
where $y$'s are Yoneda embeddings; these two are fully faithful, hence $j$ must be fully faithful (let's wave my hands and tell you that this follows from the cancellation property of the right class of the [(bo,ff)-factorization system](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28bo%2C+ff%29+factorization+system) on $\bf Cat$).

> - Does the inclusion preserve finite limits?
> - What about colimits?

I bet you want to take a look at [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preserved+limit#preservation_of_limits_that_dont_exist); not an answer, but it might produce interesting refinements of your question.

> Now let's say I have a functor $\mathcal{A} \to$ Set which is
>   faithful.
>
> - Can I extend it to a functor $\hat{\mathcal{A}} \to$ Set?

There is a formal sleight of hand that proves that the functor ${\bf CtsCat} \to {\bf Cat}$ that includes small-complete categories in categories has a left biadjoint. This left biadjoint has a name, it's the good old (dualization of the contravariant) yoneda embedding $y : {\cal A} \to [{\cal A}, {\bf Set}]^\text{op}$.

This means (since $\bf Set$ is complete) that any functor $F : {\cal A}\to \bf Set$ can be extended to a continuous functor $[{\cal A}, {\bf Set}]^\text{op} \to \bf Set$; I'd think about this being an extension, maybe even $Ran_yF$? Does this functor have a left adjoint (I'd bet $X\mapsto(A\mapsto {\bf Set}(X,FA))$; it's an easy coend juggling and dualization: these derivations are a bit blind, but it should go as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
{\bf Set}(X, \text{Ran}_yF(P)) &\cong {\bf Set}\left(X, \int_A FA^{\hom(P, yA)}\right)\\
& \cong\int_A {\bf Set}(X, FA^{PA})\\
&\cong {\bf Set}(PA, {\bf Set}(X,FA))\\
&\cong [{\cal A},{\bf Set}](P, [X,F])
\end{align*}
$$

> - Is the extension faithful?

If all I just said is true, a right adjoint is faithful precisely if the component of the counit is an objectwise epimorphism.

> - Do you have a reference for this kind of questions?

The things I said come from the $n$Lab, from the introduction to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7108.pdf) and from a few dirty computations.